# Bringing JInternalFrame on top of other JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jinternalframe

I have 2 JPanel, named as "panelMenu" and "panelTable". Both of them are added into JDesktopPane, named as "desktop". I have put a button in "panelMenu" and when it is clicked, it will bring up a JInternalFrame.

Both of the panels are set side by side in the "desktop"...here comes the problem...when I clicked on the button...the JInternalFrame will show up but it is initially at the back of the "panelTable"...how can I bring the JInternalFrame to be always on top of any other components?

//Adding panels into desktop

```
panelMenu.setBackground(Color.yellow);
panelMenu.setBounds(0,0,200,800);
panelMenu.setLayout(null);

panelTable.setBackground(Color.gray);
panelTable.setBounds(250,50,700,700);
panelTable.setLayout(null);

desktop.setLayout(null);
desktop.setSize(width, height);
desktop.setBackground(Color.gray);

desktop.add(panelMenu);
desktop.add(panelTable);
this.add(desktop);
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: `JDesktopPane` extends from `JLayeredPane`.  You could try using `JInternalFrame#moveToFront`, but this may not work, as the panels may have already been added to a position which is the same as or higher the the internal frame.  Take a look at [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for more details

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`JOptionPane.showInternalXXXDialog(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInternalMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-):

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InternalMessageDialogTest {
  private final JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("open") {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(
          desktop, "information", "modal",
          JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      }
    });
    JPanel panelMenu = new JPanel();
    panelMenu.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    panelMenu.add(button);
    panelMenu.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);

    JInternalFrame panelTable = new JInternalFrame("Table");
    panelTable.add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(30, 3)));
    panelTable.setBounds(100, 0, 200, 100);

    desktop.add(panelMenu);
    desktop.add(panelTable);
    panelMenu.setVisible(true);
    panelTable.setVisible(true);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(desktop);
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new InternalMessageDialogTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you

```
//yourDesktopPane
//panelMenu
//panelTable
//buttonMenu
//buttonTable

private void buttonMenuMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    

    panelMenu obj = new panelMenu ();
    BasicInternalFrameUI bi = (BasicInternalFrameUI) obj.getUI();
    bi.setNorthPane(null);
    obj.setBounds(0, 0, 1220, 700);//your desired values
    obj.setVisible(true);
    yourDesktopPane.add(obj);
    obj.toFront();
}

private void buttonTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    

    panelTableobj = new panelTable();
    BasicInternalFrameUI bi = (BasicInternalFrameUI) obj.getUI();
    bi.setNorthPane(null);
    obj.setBounds(0, 0, 1220, 700);//your desired values
    obj.setVisible(true);
    yourDesktopPane.add(obj);
    obj.toFront();
}
```